# how to choose datetime format in web service response in c#

Tags: oracle, web-services, visual-studio

I have a webservice in a csharp library built using vs 2013, that exchange data with an oracle application server, and I have sometimes an error when the proxy try to serialize the answer.

From what I understand, the problem is a DateTime data, that is declared as DateTime but is sent in the format 2014-01-24, and I think there is a problem in the conversion because is a format that is not compatible with client rules.

There is some way to specify the dateTime format must be used in the processing of a web service response?

Thanks,
    Luca

Comment: Can you please provide more details, show some code, and the exact error messages. What is the datatype of the element in the .WSDL file?

Comment: Hi, looks like to problem is bit different than first thought, and is the opposite.

I have this sequence in the wsdl

<sequence>

<element type="dtt:PatenteItalianaType" name="patente"/>

<element type="date" name="dataRilascio"/>

<element type="string" name="abilitazioniPossedute"/>

</sequence>

the problem is the date element: visual studios convert in a not nullable datetime field, but sometimes the value is empty, reporting a null.

Honestly I don't know who's right, and which is the standard to define a field as nullable.

I need that VS import this field as nullable datetime.

Answer (score 0):

looks like to problem is bit different than first thought, and is the opposite.

I have this sequence in the wsdl:

the problem is the date element: visual studios convert in a not nullable datetime field, but sometimes the value is empty, reporting a null.

Honestly I don't know who's right, and which is the standard to define a field as nullable. I need that VS import this field as nullable datetime